# Unable to configure database in reporting services

Tags: reporting-services, server, report, reporting

I downloaded and installed `SSRS` on my local computer.

When I get to the database portion > Change database > Create a new report server database > Next > Servername is set to my `PC` name so I click on 'Test Connection' but it fails.

What am I doing wrong?
[image: Image link]

Comment: Can you connect to the instance of SQL Server on your machine from SSMS?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not connecting via SQL server, but on my local computer itself.

Comment: haha ok nevermind, I think I figured it out. :)